# colorbox does not seem to work anymore after upgrade from 7.x-1.6 to 7.x-2.9

Tags: javascript, upgrading

I upgraded `colorbox` from 7.x-1.6 to 7.x-2.9 and now, I lost functionality of loading the pictures in a box. my page is http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/content/lodge and the centered picture in the middle, used to load nicely in a colorbox frame before the update but this does not work anymore now. The link looks like:

```
<a class="colorbox colorbox-insert-image" href="http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/sites/default/files/styles/gallery-cblarge/public/exterior---back-of-lodge-1200-x-800_0.jpg?itok=V55hQ0Bj" rel="gallery-all"><img alt="" class="image-large" height="200" src="/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/exterior---back-of-lodge-1200-x-800_0.jpg?itok=Q6e4P9RK" width="480"></a>
```

The link is being "auto-created" as follows:
In my Content type, I have added a Field `myImage` that allows me to upload and insert the image into the content. The Format of the field, I set to `Colorbox`. I setup my image styles as follows:

```
Content image style: Hide
Colorbox image style: Original image
Colorbox gallery type: Per page gallery
Colorbox caption: None
```

And don't understand how this isn't working anymore after the upgrade...
Whaty's wrong with this I'm wondering? Should I rollback to 7.x-1.6 or can I fix this?

**EDIT A**
The colorbox module is installed & enabled and it says `A light-weight, customizable lightbox plugin for jQuery 1.4.3+.` Looks like I'm using jQuery 1.4.4: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>`

**EDIT B**
I just copied `modules/colorbox/` to `libraries/colorbox/` but that didn't change much. You say the "JS lib" is not included on the page? I have 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://quaaoutlodge.com/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4"></script>`
and
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/sites/all/themes/marinelli/templates/jquery.js"></script>`
in my source code, the second line refers to `jQuery 1.8`

Comment: I have a feeling that the module itself is not available at the moment, can you check that? also make sure you are using jquery version 1.8 at least!

Comment: please see **EDIT A** above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to update the colorbox library too !

right now - the JS lib is not included in the page ...

Comment: Hi remy, please sese **EDIT B** above

Comment: no do not copy the module to libraries ! revert that pls. take a fresh copy from http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ and extract it to the libraries folder, actually /admin/reports/status will give you hints here.

Comment: yep, that was it! I downloaded the `colorbox-master.zip` extracted the archive to `/sites/all/libraries`, renamed it to `colorbox` and cleared the caches. Thanks!